# Is it legal to put a Ferrari engine in another car if you are not certified by Ferrari?

Tags: engine, swap, ferrari

Two colleagues of mine are arguing. One says that you cannot put a Ferrari engine into another car without being a certified Ferrari mechanic. Well you can do it... but unless the mechanic was certified by Ferrari you will never get this car road or track legal.

The other says that this cannot be true because that would mean a company like Ferrari has power over the law. If you're allowed to build a mechanically safe car from scratch then why would they be able to stop you with just Ferrari engines?

Answer (score 1):

In many jurisdictions, "street legal" is simply a matter of having that powertrain and that chassis previously certified by the transportation regulator, even if they came separately and were never ever sold together.

In other jurisdictions, it's the combination of chassis and engine that needs to be certified. Ferrari and being certified by them has nothing to do with it. People love creating BS stories to use as an excuse why they won't do something.